# Connect an Endpoint who has a certificate not signed by a list of Trusted CA by Salesforce

Tags: callout, soap, ssl

I have a requirement where in I have to connect Salesforce with a Govt Organization via SOAP API and the mode of authentication is via a Certificate which is signed by the Govt Body itself. The Govt body is not listed in the list of trusted CA for my instance i.e., https://cs126.salesforce.com/cacerts.jsp, and I am not able to make a secured callout as well (http instead of https)

Wanted to know if anyone has faced this issue and how I can go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with the concerned Salesforce Product team on this scenario. The Salesforce PKI team can assist with any updates to trust store.

Please consider creating a [support ticket](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) with details of the certificate that you need to add to the trust store. After performing an assessment the root will be added by the team. There isn't any public-facing doc for customers at the moment.